# Function calling inside angularJs ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Can i call function inside a ng-model in angularJs like below ?

*`<input type="text" ng-model="choice.number = itemNumber()" class="form-control" readonly>`*

Any help appreciated ?

Comment: use `ng-init` instead of calling function

Comment: ng-change ? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Comment: @HJz Actually am getting the value of choice.number from the database, so i have to use JS function to call PHP function and getting value form the DB so i this case i have to use function here

Comment: @Groben _The ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model_ 
Here in my case user never change value of the field because it is read only field so in this case i don't think ng-change can help

Comment: you can use similar to this `ng-init="choice.number = itemNumber()"`

Comment: @HJz Thank you so much man , it works !!!
`<input type="text" ng-init="choice.number = itemNumber()"   ng-model="choice.number" class="form-control" readonly>`
Why don't you can write is as answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use `ng-init`

```
<input type="text" ng-model="choice.number" ng-init="choice.number = itemNumber()" >
```

Answer (score 0):

If  you do like that you must likely to get *Error: [ngModel:nonassign]*. For more information You can see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel. If you need to call function in ng-modle best way would be updating it in controller.For example

```
<div class="result" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="choice.number" class="form-control" readonly>
{{choice.number}}
 </div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        var hello = function(){
        return 5;
    }

    $scope.choice = {number:hello()};

    //console.log($scope.hello());
});
</script>
```

I hope you will find this helpful. you can also define the function using `$scope.hello` instead of `var hello`.